# A word that describes a meeting of 9 people?

Tags: synonyms

I have heard a word before that describes a meeting of 9 people.

It could also be a governing body or syndicate that specifically consists of 9 people.

I can't remember it for the life of me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a word [***nonumvirate,***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vir#Derived_terms_2) derived in a similar way to *triumvirate:*

> From Latin *triumvīrātus.*
>
> 1. A group or association of three, especially three statesmen.
>
> [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triumvirate)]

That word is ultimately derived from *trium* ‎(“of three”) + *vir* ‎(“man”).